Unable to link a model Object to another model, which takes in a OnetoOnefiled
So I have a login page, which also has an option to register if you're a new user. The registration phase consists of two pages, one where the user enters their personal information, and two where the user sets the username and password. Right now I am storing them as strings just to get my website running. I am successful in creating a model object for the personal information, and also successful in linking that object to the newly created login details object. I am trying to compare the entered values of the user on the login page to the objects stored in the database and once they match, I want to be able to retrieve the role of the user, which is a part of the UserData object and navigate to the appropriate dashboard. I dont seem to to get it working
Registration.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const RegistrationPage = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [latestUserData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLatestObject = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/latest-object/');
        console.log(response)
        setUserData(response.data.user_data);
        console.log(response.data.user_data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching latest object:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchLatestObject();
  }, []);

  
  const handleRegister = () => {
    console.log(username, password)
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/', {
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
      'user_data': latestUserData
      })
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
    navigate('/');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Registration</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleRegister}>Register</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegistrationPage;

Models.py
class UserData(models.Model):
ROLE_CHOICES = (
    ('Recruiter', 'Recruiter'),
    ('Manager', 'Manager'),
    ('Business Development Partner', 'Business Development Partner'),
    ('Business Development Partner Manager', 'Business Development Partner Manager'),
    ('Account Manager', 'Account Manager'),
)

fullName = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
aadhaarNumber = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
dateOfBirth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
maritalStatus = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
emergencyContact = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
phoneNumber = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0000000000), MaxValueValidator(9999999999)], blank=True, null=True)
emailID = models.EmailField(validators=[EmailValidator()], blank=True, null=True)
emergencyContactNumber = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0000000000), MaxValueValidator(9999999999)], blank=True, null=True)
jobTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
departmentName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
joiningDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
employmentType = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
prevCompany = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
prevDesignation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
relevantSkills = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
documentAcknowledged = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
pfUAN = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
esiNO = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.fullName if self.fullName else "Unnamed User"

class LoginDetails(models.Model):
    user_data = models.OneToOneField(UserData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)  # Note: It's recommended to use hashed passwords in production
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

Views.py
def get_latest_user(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    latest_object_id = UserData.objects.latest('id').id
    user_data = UserData.objects.get(id=latest_object_id)
    serialized_user_data = serialize("json", user_data)
    return JsonResponse({'user_data': serialized_user_data})
else:
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Method not allowed'}, status=405)

@csrf_exempt
def verify_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
    # Retrieve stored login details
    stored_login = LoginDetails.objects.filter(username=data.get('username')).first()
    print(stored_login.username)

    if stored_login:
        # Compare the passwords directly
        if data.get('password') == stored_login.password:
            # Authentication successful
            user_role = stored_login.user_data.role if stored_login.user_data and stored_login.user_data.role else None
            print(user_role)
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Login successful', 'role': user_role})
        else:
            # Password does not match
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid password'}, status=401)
    else:
        # Username not found
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid username'}, status=401)

return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'}, status=405)

Urls.py
path('api/register/', LoginDetailsViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'}), name='register'),
    path('api/login/', verify_login, name='user-login'),
    path('latest-object/', get_latest_user, name='latest_object_detail'),

Employeeregistration.py (Only posting the api call part)
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

// Make an HTTP POST request using Axios
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit_user_data/', userData)
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Data sent successfully:', response.data);
    // Reset the form after successful submission
    setUserData({ ...userData});
    navigate('/usernameregistration');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error sending data:', error);
  });

};
Right now I get UserData is not iterable. But I also tried to send the userdata object id instead of the whole object, but didn't work either (Failed to retrieve the role)
Any help would be appreciated

Why are you creating a second model LoginDetails with a one to one relationship instead of just putting the fields from LoginDetails into the UserData model? Additionally, you would probably have a much easier time if you weren't creating a custom user model inheriting from just Model, you should inherit from AbstractUser instead. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model
